# Add custom user fields to Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am new to programming and Meteor.js. I am trying to build a question app where an admin can post questions, then after awhile be able to mark them as true or false. When user clicks on "Yes" or "No" the app adds their user id to either `usersTrue` or `usersTrue` arrays. Also the question `_id` is added to the users profile so it can check if the user has already answered the question. Finally, when the admin clicks true or false it loops through the list of users who answered correctly and increases their     `rightCount` by 1 or if they answered incorrect increases their `wrongCount` by 1.

I have figured out how to insert the user's id into the right question array.

My question is how can I add custom fields to the user when their account is created, so I can check if the user has answered the question already.

I have tried creating /server/user.js with `onCreateUser`

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
profile = _.insert({
    questionsAnswered: [],
    rightCount: 0,
    wrongCount: 0
});

user.profile = profile

return user;
```

If I am doing this completely wrong or there is a more efficient way of doing this whole process, I would be interested in hearing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. You can try this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  profile = {
      questionsAnswered: [],
      rightCount: 0,
      wrongCount: 0
  };

  user.profile = profile

  return user;
});
```

Comment: Make sure you set up allow/deny rules for your users collection because in meteor, the profile key of the user document is freely available to the user for updates. So basically, if you don't restrict it, a user can change rightCount at will.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. It seems I was trying to overcomplicate it. I will change the allow/deny rules once I have app done for public use. Thanks again.